# Is there a way to calculate all the gas used in a transaction from within a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, opcode

If I use gasleft() and the beginning and end of the function then I only capture the amount of gas used between those two points. Is there a way to capture all of the gas used then to multiply that times the tx.gasprice?

Chainlink using gasleft() https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/KeeperRegistry1_1.sol#L723.

Chainlink just adds a buffer on top of the amount of gas reported to handle for example the 21,000 gas for the first function call itself. They add 80k gas https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/KeeperRegistry1_1.sol#LL672C49-L672C70.

Is the total amount of gas used static? This of course being separate from the gas price which changes.

Thanks

Comment: The total amount of gas used is not static, because for one thing, it depends on the execution path that the call takes (e.g. if-block vs else-block if they use different amounts of gas). Also, the execution path cannot generally be predicted without actually executing it, so you can only know the total gas used at the end of the call.